# How to create a new report

Tags: civireport

I need to create a new report, an italian postal bulletin for donation or subscription, as in the below image.

[image]

Do you have any suggestions on where to start?
I mean:

- I must create an extensions?
- What's the tool (the best one) to write reports in CiviCRM?
- ....

Thanks for your attention

Marcello

Comment: The image is too small to see -- can you upload a larger version?

Comment: With more clarification of what data you are needing to output. That image appears to be a form with a separate 'box' for each character

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension based on report template using Civix

please refer to the link 
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Report-Template+Extension

Also the image which you have attached is not very clear..

Answer (score 0):

There are some good suggestions for different ways of creating reports in answer to this question that I posted last year.

[How can I make it easier for users to generate the reports they need?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/73/how-can-i-make-it-easier-for-users-to-generate-the-reports-they-need)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the quality of the image, this is better.

[image]

Pratically, for each contact I must create all the standard stucture (lines, boxes, ...) and fill the boxes with the contact personal data (names, addresses, ...)

Marcello