# Complex multiple Selects in Custom Coded Reports

Tags: mysql, reports, custom-reports

Following on from my query  here [How to write custom report SQL](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14975/how-to-write-custom-report-sql)

(CiviCRM 4.7 on WordPress)

I built the SQL I needed as step 1, which works fine in mysql / phpmyadmin.

I have used civix, to generate a module and to clone the 'empty' report from 101 and register the report - so far so go, if I want a report that says 'hello'.

Next step slot in my SQL and test ....  and within civi it gives sysntax errors.

Debug shows that it is inserting SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS all over the SQL, where as I need it only on the final select.

Although my requirement is simple my SQL is complex, and I can't achieve it in one SELECT statement ( maybe possible by a SQL wizard ), as it requires contact relationships in two directions and a 'pivot' of contributions, it builds 3 temporary table and joins them up in a final select.

My main question is 'can CiviReport only handle a single select?'  and the second question is is there something I can do, or should I just resort to coding outside CiviReport structures?

Thanks so far for the help given, it has been fantastic.

Eaxmple issue

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpcontrhist AS
   SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS house_id,
     YEAR(contr.receive_date) memb_year,
        contr.total_amount memb_amount
FROM
   tmpareareps,
   civicrm_contribution contr
WHERE
   house_id = contr.contact_id;


Database Error Code: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual      that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near    'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpcontrhist AS SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS house_id, ' at line 21, 1064
```

Answer (score 1):

In the CRM/Report folder: grep -r -i "TEMPORARY" *

This gives you some existing reports that use temp tables which you can look at to get some ideas.

`Form/Activity.php
Form/Contribute/Detail.php
etc...`

Comment: Gosh, this is far harder than slotting in a bit of SQL and away you go!  Need to learn a whole new framework for a one off. Not sure if it is etiquette but any one want to quote to code this up  - I can provide working SQL, or if this isn't the right place - apologies - and advise :)

Comment: Take a look at "custom search" instead. You don't have all the widgets but you can just plug in your sql. https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension#CreateaModuleExtension-Addacustomsearch

Comment: Thanks, an easier starting point.  By the way any reason why in the example I looked at the buildtemptables was called in the from function rather than select  - answering my own question maybe select deals with columns, and in the case in looking at the temp table logic requires stuff that isn't available that early.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have a limited MySQL knowledge, but I think you need to join the two tables? So I would do something like

```
FROM tmpareareps tmp JOIN civicrm_contribution_recur recur ON tmp.house_id = recur.contact_id
```

Comment: The SQL join fine.   I could use  JOIN  or just use the WHERE, it has the same impact, the issue is CiviCRM  ADD  the SQL_CALC_FOUND to the SELECT  which is invalid in the CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AS..  The code I provide to Civi does not have SQL_CALC_FOUND  in it.