# Custom report Action not working on new development

Tags: custom-reports, debugging

I have now, after a steep learning curve built a custom report based on the  kind help I have has so far.

[How to write custom report SQL](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14975/how-to-write-custom-report-sql)

But I have an issue, that I don't know how to effectively resolve.

The report works online fine now with the desired output.

I built the report using the Example 101 - starting with 'Empty Report' and adding my SQL & columns as required.

But when I select an 'action' such as 'print' 'print to pdf' etc, there is a brief pause a refresh and nothing ..

Nothing is appearing in the php logs.

I have debug on.  Nothing is showing in the CiviCRM log output.

There are no browser console JS errors.

All other reports perform as expected.

I'm working through CiviCRM debugging, any pointers here please - I'm so close but so far!  (CiviCRM 4.7 - WordPress)

Answer (score 1):

OK,

I tried deleting the report and recreating the report from the template, and like magic the functions started working.  Seems that CiviCRM has certain ways about it that developers need to know. ( is there a list somewhere ).

Moving on to the next part suppressing duplicate row content and page braking on sections. Getting closer to the goal :)

Comment: Alan - if you want developer tips, come join us at http://chat.civicrm.org in the #dev channel!